# Requirejs + Backbone.js: TypeError: Can't pass in the router - Router is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js, requirejs

I am still trying to understand how `requirejs` works and I believe that I have followed the docs and other tutorials carefully. But I seem can't get certain `module` loaded, for instance, the `router`.

This is the view model where I have the problem,

```
// File: js/view/list.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'router', // Request router.js

    // Pull in the Collection module.
    'collection/contacts',

    // Load the template
    'text!template/list.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, Router, ProjectCollection, Template){

        console.log(Router); // I have passed the router as Router!
        var router = Router();
        router.initialize();

});
```

result,

> undefined
>
> list.js (line 17) TypeError: Router is not a function
>
> var router = Router();

This is the router code on the root of `js` folder,

```
// File: js/router.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'view/list'
], function($, _, Backbone, ProjectListView){

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'list_contacts':    'renderListContactsPage'
        },

        renderListContactsPage: function () {
            var projectListView = new ProjectListView();
            projectListView.listContactsPage();
        }
    });

    var initialize = function(){
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong and how can I fix it?

Other files,

```
// File: js/main.js
require.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone-min',
        text: 'lib/text/text'
    },

    shim: {
        jquery: {
          exports: '$'
        },
        underscore: {
          exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
          exports: 'Backbone'
        }
      }
});

require([
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'app'
], function(App){
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    App.initialize();
});
```

And,

```
// File: js/app.js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router', // Request router.js
], function($, _, Backbone, Router){

    console.log(Router); // Here no error at all!

    var initialize = function(){

        // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
        Router.initialize();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Comment: Well, you have `Router()` in `js/view/list.js` versus `Router.initialize();` in `js/app.js`

Comment: I get the same error even if I do this `Router.initialize();` in `js/view/list.js`.

Comment: But did you remember to remove the `var router = Router();` line in that case?

Answer (score 2):

The error message explains it all, really: the return value of your Router module (router.js) is an *object literal*, not a function so invoking `()` on it will cause an exception (distilled in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8DcQ/)).

It should be enough to change the call to:

```
// (...)
console.log(Router); // I have passed the router as Router!
Router.initialize();
```

Alternatively, you could change Router to actually return a function which returns an object with `initialize` function, it's up to you to decide which solution is more readable.

Comment: This should be 'accepted answer'. @kryger explains the situation quite simple.